# Unable to install node couchbase

Tags: node.js, npm, couchbase

The couchbase builderror.log file is completely empty. Everything installs fine with npm install, no errors on screen or in the log.

Relevant details:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/david_fells/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin:/usr/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Users/david_fells/.node_modules_global/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
$ node -v
v0.10.40
$ python -V
Python 2.7.6
```

Starting the app (node index.js  or  npm start):

```
[2015-09-30T15:26:23] [ERROR] [Error: Module did not self-register.]
[2015-09-30T15:26:23] [ERROR] { [Error: Cannot find module './build/default/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
[2015-09-30T15:26:23] [ERROR] { [Error: Cannot find module './build/Debug/DTraceProviderBindings'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
/Users/david_fells/projects/inmarCDM/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:152
  throw new Error('Failed to locate couchnode native binding' +
  ^

Error: Failed to locate couchnode native binding (maybe check builderror.log!)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/david_fells/projects/inmarCDM/node_modules/couchbase/lib/binding.js:152:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.cls_wrapMethod [as _load] (/Users/david_fells/projects/inmarCDM/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:230:38)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/david_fells/projects/inmarCDM/node_modules/couchbase/lib/couchbase.js:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

NPM log has this:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/Users/david_fells/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/david_fells/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.40
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart inmarCDM@0.0.5
6 info start inmarCDM@0.0.5
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info inmarCDM@0.0.5 Failed to exec start script
9 error inmarCDM@0.0.5 start: `node index.js`
9 error Exit status 255
10 error Failed at the inmarCDM@0.0.5 start script.
10 error This is most likely a problem with the inmarCDM package,
10 error not with npm itself.
10 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
10 error     node index.js
10 error You can get their info via:
10 error     npm owner ls inmarCDM
10 error There is likely additional logging output above.
11 error System Darwin 14.4.0
12 error command "/Users/david_fells/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/node" "/Users/david_fells/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/npm" "start"
13 error cwd /Users/david_fells/projects/inmarCDM
14 error node -v v0.10.40
15 error npm -v 1.4.28
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here's the full output from an npm silly: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34647212/npm.log

Comment: Just a thought, David, could it be trying to run a different version of Python? Perhaps if the script specifically checks if Python is above like 2.5 but below 3.0.

Comment: Python version is within the required version range - 2.7.x

Mac OS - happens on EL Capitan and Yosemite both.

Comment: I've added the output from a silly level npm install to the original post.

Comment: Please, run `cd /Users/david_fells/projects/inmarCDM`, then `/Users/david_fells/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/node /Users/david_fells/.nvm/v0.10.40/bin/npm start` and post the results.

Comment: Well, it seems to have just started working today, after another round of deleting node_modules, selecting nvm version, npm install, npm start... not really sure what to make of that as I've done nothing different and nothing has changed on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [thread](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/problem-node-js-couchbase-sdk/1111) from couchbase forum.

It seems that your environment is lacking some prerequisites of `node-gyp`

Then check `node-gyp`'s official [readme](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation).

May the odds be ever in your favor